# Store cookies with WebKit (python)

Tags: application-development, python, webkit

So I was watching the ["Create Your First Ubuntu App"-Video](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) from Jono Bacon and got the idea, to create a simple app. That creates a window with a WebView und opens the URL to Google Keep. 
Everything is fine, I now just need to store cookies for authentication, I googled a little, but since I am not familiar with python I couldn't get it working.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/G4dhxsWZ) is the part with the WebView. Does anyone know how I can get this to store cookies now?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This Stackoverflow answer shows how to use WebKit with Python through introspection http://stackoverflow.com/a/15800193/307826

Comment: I've seen this answer before and tried it but it did not work.